# When logging in to Oracle Enterprise Manager, it is asking me for the credentials again. Why?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to log in to: https://localhost:5500/em/login

First, I entered my credentials at the bottom right area. Then, I clicked the button.
After that, a pop-up appeared at the top of the page.

Why is it asking me this?
What should I input?

I tried putting the same values, but I still couldn't get through.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the solution from: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/admqs/getting-started-with-database-administration.html#GUID-06C767B0-B435-4C6B-9123-C39C030DF457

> 3.4.3 Starting EM Express for a PDB To start EM Express for a PDB, ensure that the PDB is open in read/write mode and then try one of the
>   following methods described in this topic (in the order shown):
>
> Connect to the CDB$ROOT container for the CDB that includes the PDB,
>   and issue the following SQL statement to configure the global port for
>   the CDB:
>
> exec dbms_xdb_config.setglobalportenabled(TRUE);

Answer (score 5):

One Note, if you are trying to log into the Container rather than the Pluggable database, put the Container name as "CDB$ROOT". I tried my container name and it didn't work, but putting that in allowed me to connect to the Container itself. Good luck!